# Postgres 8.1 pg_trgm plugin doesn’t work with unicode chars

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to get the pg_trgm plugin in postgres server 8.1 to work with unicode chars?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/release-8-4.html)  it's a feature available from version 8.4 or higher